# Hyper-V VM Remote Desktop Woes

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, remote-desktop

I was able to access a VM on a Hyper-V server the other day, but now I can't.  I don't know what went wrong; Remote Desktop is enabled on win server (2008 R2) and windows 7 VM...  I can't figure this out... what do I need to enable?  As I said, I could access it yesterday.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try? Are you connecting from one VM to another, or from a physical host to a VM on another serve? Can you ping the VM? Can you open the VM from the Hyper-V console and verify it is running? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would question if the VM still has full network access.  Use VM console to try to get to something else on the network from the 2 VM's.  If that works fine, then:
2. Check that Remote Desktop is enabled in each VM OS and that your account has access.  You know RDP 3389 port is listening when you try to connect remotely and get a popup to authenticate.

Comment: 1. I can access it over the network via its computer name from windows explorer, and in that machine access the machine I'm trying to connect from, so its on the workstation.  2.  Each VM has remote desktop enabled (using the less secure method of letting everyone connect but requiring user ID/password).  I'll try the port.  I tried turning off firewall on VM and server, but that didn't help.  Could it be some driver issue, or some network adapter issue?

Comment: I suppose so but I've never seen an issue with the hundreds of VM's I've managed on dozens of Hyper-V servers.

Comment: I know and I've not had any issues...  I did export it and import it to another location, so at first this was the issue, but then I got it back up and working, but no luck lately...

Comment: Oh, and I had a folder rename + computer rename as a part of this change... don't know if that changes anything...

Comment: THat was it, I needed to rename the computer, and it works great.  I renamed to something other than what the old name was...

Comment: Yes you can't have two computers with the same name on the same network, DNS will have issues.  Also be careful you don't duplicate the MAC address in the VM configure file or you'll have IP packet issues.

Comment: OK, Thanks.  I deleted the old machine with that name too, but yes, it has to be that.